# Passing variable with single quote in javascript

Tags: javascript, regex

I have an onClick call on a link:

```
<a onClick="fomateName('Andrew Dsouza')"> //this is working good
```

The problem is the variable inside fomateName would contain single quotes and  my fomateName Takes a variable like

var a='Andrew D'souza'. Need to format a variable present with single quote Ex;

```
<a onClick="fomateName('a')"> which turns to 

<a onClick="fomateName('Andrew D'souza')"> //this is not working ,because present of single quote
```

Any Idea how to pass text with proper quotes in a javascript.

with single quote not the name actually

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
<a onClick="fomateName('Andrew D\'souza')"> <!-- this will work -->
```

`\` use backslashes to escape '

Lets say if you have function like this =>

```
function fomateName(txt){
    alert(txt);
}
```

and invoking it from anchor =>

```
<a onClick="fomateName('Andrew D\'souza')"> <!-- this will alert "Andrew D'souza" -->
```

Comment: I need to format the variable which reolves to a name Like Andre D'souza

Comment: If you pass a variable through you wont need to worry about escaping it should just work.

Comment: @saum22 When you have wrapped params inside function in single quotes `''` and want variable including same `'` (single quote) you have to use \ before `'`

Comment: but how to do it for a variable which contains single quote

Comment: @saum22 you can define variable like this => `var a = "Andrew D'souza";` or `var a = 'Andrew D\'souza';` , but I suggest to use double quotes

Comment: the list of name are coming from database I am not define at my end.that why I need to do it for a variable

Comment: @saum22 Then you have to parse values in SQL or in server side script to be able to pass them in JavaScript function in right way

Answer (score 1):

Escape the quote with backslashes.

```
<a onClick="fomateName('Andrew D\'souza')">
//this is not working ,because present of single quote
```

Answer (score 0):

You can escape the quote with a backslash..

```
fomateName('Andrew D\'souza');
```

This should work anyway:

```
var name = "Andrew D'souza";
fomateName(name);
```

Comment: but its not working for a a variable call present with single quote

Comment: @saum22 `<a onClick="fomateName('a')">` should be `<a onClick="fomateName(a)">`

Answer (score 0):

You can wrap it in double quotes like so:

```
   <a onClick="fomateName("Andrew D'souza")"> //this is not working ,because present of single quote
```

Never mind, just realized it already has double quotes, yeah use backslash for escape like so:

```
  <a onClick="fomateName('Andrew D\'souza')">
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this. Use `backslash` - It will escape the quote breaks

```
<a onClick="fomateName('Andrew D\'souza')">
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use escape character

```
<a onclick="formateName('AdrewD\'souza')">
```